# system("history") not working

Tags: c++, linux

I've run into a snag, I'm trying to implement a linux shell program of sorts with C++ and many of my commands seem to work, however, when I try to get the history(list all recently executed commands) I get an error of "sh: 1: history: not found" the below line is all that runs in the area, what is the issue?

```
 system("history"); //produces the error above ^
```

If I do

```
$ history
```

from the command line it's fine...why is it not fine in C++?

Comment: Because `history` is not an executable in your `PATH` but rather a shell command provided by `bash`.

Comment: So if you are coding a shell, you need to implement `history` yourself, as a builtin (much like `cd` should also be a builtin)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`system` executes a program using `/bin/sh`, but `history` is a bash builtin.

You might look at the contents of `~/.bash_history` instead. (Note (by leemes) `.bash_history` is only updated after closing a previous bash session, as well as it is not updated by executing a command with `system`.)

Comment: But note that `.bash_history` is only updated after closing a previous bash session, as well as it is not updated by executing a command with `system`. It won't help if OP tries to get a history of commands executed with `system`.

Comment: I'll have to check out the ~/.bash_history, thanks for the pointer, @Csq!!

Comment: is there any way of calling history from C ? Using bash_history doesn't solve the use case.

Answer (score 2):

Because it's a bash shell builtin not necessarily accessible through /bin/sh -c` (which may be the bourne shell).